# spring expression to get file size?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration. i have seen below example over the web.

```
<int:router input-channel="inChannel" expression="payload.paymentType">
    <int:mapping value="CASH" channel="cashPaymentChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="CREDIT" channel="authorizePaymentChannel"/>
    <int:mapping value="DEBIT" channel="authorizePaymentChannel"/>
</int:router>
```

similar to above logic, my requirement is if payload lenggh is zero, then it should map to one channel and if payload size is more than one then it should be directed to different channel. How can i achieve it using SpEL?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your payload a `String`?

Comment: payload is Message<File>

Comment: So you want to test the file size?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a `Message<File>`, using `payload` in the expression would be referring to the `File`.  You can access any of `File`'s methods in the expression.  The following will route to `outputChannelB` if the file doesn't exist or is zero-length, or `outputChannelA` otherwise:

```
<int:router input-channel="inputChannel" expression="payload?.length() > 0 ? 'outputChannelA' : 'outputChannelB'" />
```

Note the use of the "safe-navigation" operator `?.` for null safety.